# Echo or preview text changed using sed -i

Tags: sed

Using **sed** you can easily change text in multiple files, eg:

```
 sed -i 's/cashtestUS/cheque_usd/g' *.xml
```

The problem is that this has tremendous power, and a complex regular expression could easily have unforeseen consequences.

Is there a simple way to do either:

1) Echo the changes made
2) Run **sed** in a preview mode, so that the potential changes can be previewed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run in preview mode without the `-i`:

```
sed -e 's/cashtestUS/cheque_usd/g' *.xml
```

(The `-e` is not necessary; it just says the next argument is the `sed` script, or one part of the `sed` script.)  This writes all the output to standard output.  You'd probably pipe it through `less` (or `more`), or pass it through `grep` to see that the changed lines were those you expected.  Or you might process one file at a time and run a difference:

```
for file in *.xml
do
    echo "$file"
    sed -e 's/cashtestUS/cheque_usd/g' "$file" | diff -u "$file" -
done
```

Or …

Comment: 2020 : Withe regards to the above Could u share how to  make 'for' read recursively from a folder and all its sub folders, on say *.php , *.inc files  and then do the 'sed' operation ? ... Something like a global search and replace that we can run from the command line ? I know that printing out line numbers is difficult but at least with this method u can see the filename being acted on

Comment: @MarcoZen — That stops being a `sed` question and becomes a shell question.  Assuming a sufficiently recent version of Bash (4.x probably  – 4.3 worked; not the 3.x version found on macOS by default), you can use `shopt -s globstar` and then `for file in **/*.inc **/*.php; do …whatever…; done` (see [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion)).  You might also want to use `shopt -s nullglob`.  It's likely that `zsh` has an equivalent mechanism; I don't know about other shells.

Answer (score 1):

sed have several 'debug/display action'

- `=` display the current line number
- `l` display the current working buffer content with a `$` at the end of the content
- `i` and `a` could be used to show a trace like `i \
  Debug trace here`
- if holding buffer is not used a `h;s/.*/Debug Trace here/;g` is usefull and does not appear at end of line treatment like `i`or `a`

sample:

```
echo "line 1
and two" | sed ':a
=;h;s/.*/Before substitution/;g;l
s/..$/-/
=;l
t a'
```

Comment: This became a infinite command ... dont run ... on a opensuse 42.3 box ...